# string.replaceAll java doesn't work with lookaround regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a json string like this:

```
string = "{name={first=sam, last=vo}, hobbies={hobby1=football, hobby2=swimming}}"
```

And I want to remove the "name=" and the "hobbies=", so that I use this pattern: `\w*\=(?={)` ->tested using editPadPro

However, when I use the replace all in java:

```
String pattern = "\\w*\\=(?={)";
String removedParent = string.replaceAll(pattern, "");
```

I got this error message

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 7
\w*\=(?={)"
```

Can you please give me some advices to get this work?

Regards,

Sam

Comment: Do you want to remove other names like "first=, last=, hobby1=,hobby2=" or only the top level names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `{` character is a special character in regex syntax which denotes an amount (for instance `\d{2}` denotes 2 digits). In your case, you want to match the literal `{`, meaning that you need to *escape* the `{` character, so you need to change your regex to this: `"\\w*\\=(?=\\{)";`.

For me, this yielded:

> {{first=sam, last=vo}, {hobby1=football, hobby2=swimming}}

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
```

comes because of your "{" in `"\\w*\\=(?={)"`. "{" and "}" are special characters to state characters repetitions as you might know ...

just try to escape it like that `"\\w*\\=(?=\\{)"`. and since you're working with json , please consider using a JSON-Parser like:

- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)
- [net.json](http://www.json.org/java/)